# Javascript Auto-Refresh content - missing data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, amazon-s3, amazon-connect

Hello I do have data which needs to be refreshed every 5 seconds but I can't retrieve the value after the refresh. I've tried this:
First, I've used the refresh function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div_refresh').load("userdetail.html");
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#div_refresh').load("userdetail.html")
}, 5000);
});
```

This it is loading + refreshing my DIV, as per the HTML (userdetail.html)

```html
<html>
<p>Username: <span id="Name"></span></br>
    Routing Profile: <span id="routingProfile"></span></br>
    Agent State: <span id="State"></span></br>
    State TimeStamp: <span id="TimeStamp"></span></br>
    State Duration: <span id="Duration"></span></p>
</html>
```

This is working, DIV it is refreshing, however, after the first refresh all data that it is being populated through the script:

```js
    /* agent.js */
        connect.agent(function(agent) {
            document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = agent.getName();
            document.getElementById("routingProfile").innerHTML = agent.getRoutingProfile().name;
            document.getElementById("State").innerHTML= agent.getState().name;
            document.getElementById("TimeStamp").innerHTML = agent.getState().startTimestamp;
            document.getElementById("Duration").innerHTML = agent.getStateDuration();
        });
```

No longer appears, it just returns the paragraph within the names, but the 'span' value doesn't.
On my main HTML (index.html) this is how the setup it is set:

```html
 <div id="div_refresh"></div>
 <script id="agent" type="text/javascript" src="./agent.js"></script>
 <script src="./reload.js"></script>
```

This is how it looks like before the refresh and the span data disapear
https://iili.io/c6p8pS.png
Any ideas?

Comment: your snippet is incomplete (no HTML, declare the jQuery)

Comment: Also, I would suggest "every 5 seconds "after" the last one since it might take more than 5 seconds to do so - use a Promise to do that  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise - jQuery ajax BTW returns a promise you can utilize to do that fairly simply

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to this is instead of reloading the div every x seconds is to trigger a function on the `agent.onRefresh` event in streams. For example...

```
connect.agent(async function (agent) {

  agent.onRefresh(handleAgentRefresh);

});

function handleAgentRefresh(agent) {
  var changedRoutingProfileName = agent.getRoutingProfile().name;
  if (changedRoutingProfileName != document.getElementById('routingProfile').innerHTML ) {
    document.getElementById('routingProfile').innerHTML = changedRoutingProfileName ;
  }
}
```

This way the routing profile name will update automatically when streams reports that it has changed. and you don't have to reload at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally untested and will not actually run here.  Uing a promise we can get the results, paste them in, then once that is done to the "agent" thing, then after 5 seconds, trigger it to start over.

FWIW, I change the id since "#divxxx" making the id match the tag is not a good practice.  I also used some CSS and remove your invalid `</br>` and used CSS to style it instead - but that is not part of your question, more me formatting it with CSS.

```js
$(function() {
  function fetchMe(url) {
    return jQuery.ajax(url, {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'html'
    });
  }

  $('#refreshed-content').on("go-get-another", function() {
      $.when(fetchMe('userdetail.html'))
        .then(function(results) { // Resolve
          $('#refreshed-content').html(results.data);
        }, function() { // Reject!
          console.log('Something broke!');
        }).then(function() {
          // you decide if this is the right place to go get what was pasted in: I have less experience with this area.
          connect.agent(function(agent) {
            document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = agent.getName();
            document.getElementById("routingProfile").innerHTML = agent.getRoutingProfile().name;
            document.getElementById("State").innerHTML = agent.getState().name;
            document.getElementById("TimeStamp").innerHTML = agent.getState().startTimestamp;
            document.getElementById("Duration").innerHTML = agent.getStateDuration();
          });
        })
        // set a 5 second delay then trigger next load
        .then(value =>
          new Promise(resolve =>
            setTimeout(() => resolve(value), 5000)
          )
        ).then(function() {
          $('#refreshed-content').trigger('go-get-another');
        });
    })
    // start the ball rolling:
    .trigger('go-get-another');
});
```

```css
.content-block {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: coumn;
}

.content-row {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="refreshed-content" class="content-block">
  <div class="content-row user-name">Username:<span id="Name"></span></div>
  <div class="content-row"> Routing Profile:<span id="routingProfile"></span></div>
  <span class="content-row"> Agent State:<span id="State"></span></span>
  <p class="content-row"> State TimeStamp:<span id="TimeStamp"></span></p>
  <div class="content-row"> State Duration:<span id="Duration"></span></div>
</div>
```